# Python 3.7 and psycopg2. ImportError: DLL load failed

Tags: python, module, importerror, python-3.7

I tried the Python 3.7 on Windows 10 and got `ImportError` of `psycopg2` module which installed from pip.

In `psycopg2\__init__.py` there is an import from pyd:

```
from psycopg2._psycopg import (                     # noqa
    BINARY, NUMBER, STRING, DATETIME, ROWID,

    Binary, Date, Time, Timestamp,
    DateFromTicks, TimeFromTicks, TimestampFromTicks,

    Error, Warning, DataError, DatabaseError, ProgrammingError, IntegrityError,
    InterfaceError, InternalError, NotSupportedError, OperationalError,

    _connect, apilevel, threadsafety, paramstyle,
    __version__, __libpq_version__,
)
```

And this causes `ImportError: DLL load failed: Can't find specified moudule.` while the file `Python37\Lib\site-packages\psycopg2\_psycopg.cp37-win_amd64.pyd` exists!

Whats wrong with import? It's regression?

Answer (score 2):

According to installation prerequisites of psycopg2 [psycopg2-prerequisites](http://initd.org/psycopg/docs/install.html#prerequisites):

- Python 2 versions from 2.6 to 2.7
- Python 3 versions from 3.2 to 3.6

You'd better uninstall python 3.7 and install 3.6 instead, or install 3.6 along with 3.7. and create an alias for 3.6